Why does Reduce not work with Ceiling?
Consider the following code:
Clear["Global`*"]

sol[j_] := sol[j] = 
   Reduce[k >= 0 && Log[Ceiling[k!/3]]/Log[2] <= Log[j!]/Log[2], k, Integers]
LowSample = Max[k /. Solve[sol[5], {k}, Integers]]


Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.

I want to get LowSample=5, but the code is not working.
How do we fix sol[j] and LowSample?

Do you really need that Ceiling? Also, possibly LogGamma will work better that those logs of factorials.

@DanielLichtblau I want a generalized method to solving inequalities with logs of any equations. That includes ceiling. How would you write these equations?
